# Imperial Upright Freezer IFC2111A alarm not working

Tags: alarm, freezer

I have an Imperial Upright Freezer IFC2111A. For years, the alarm has not worked on it. I just had an "open door" incident the other night and lost everything - the alarm never went off.

I'm unable to locate a manual, and was wondering if anyone knew how to reset/test/fix the alarm on this freezer.

Thank you

Comment: Have you try to contact Imperial?  They should have customer service phone/email.

Comment: Standalone alarms are also an option, not specific to your make/model of freezer. Then again, depending how old the freezer is, you might be better off just replacing it with a more efficient new one. If you have a space for it, a chest freezer is both more efficient and less subject to open door issues.

Comment: Chest freezers are also more efficient for loosing things way down at the bottom and not being able to quickly get in, find what you're looking for, get out. _grumble grumble grumble_ - _hates his chest freezer, looking for an upright_.